# Cocoa -Adding a menu item programmatically

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, menu

How can I add a menu item inside a sub menu programmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`-[NSMenu addItem:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000267-addItem_) et al, e.g.:

```
NSMenu *subMenu = ...;
NSMenuItem *item = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"foo" 
                    action:@selector(fooClicked:) keyEquivalent:@""]; 
[item autorelease];
[item setTarget:self];
[subMenu addItem:item];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```
let subMenu = NSMenu()
let menuItem = NSMenuItem(
    title: "Menu item title",
    action: #selector(menuItemClicked(_:)),
    keyEquivalent: ""
)
menuItem.target = self
menuItem.toolTip = "Menu item tooltip"
subMenu.addItem(menuItem)
```